# Why does Garageband always clip the beginning of my recording?

Tags: garage-band

Whenever I record vocals and/or guitar on Garageband and look back, the waveform for the start of a bar is always a fraction before the actual bar line:

[image]

It means it's impossible to overdub/re-record a section because when the 4-click intro ends, it starts recording fractionally after my first chord and you get nasty clipping artifacts.

I'm using a software drum track as a 'click'. I used to think my old Mac was perhaps the issue but I have a new, pretty high iMac and a PreSonus AudioBox USB 96 interface - low end but I've seen loads of people use these without problems.

I know GB is basic but I also know people are able to use it for production and I don't want to just blame the software and upgrade to Logic Pro assuming that will fix anything.

Is this normal and how am I supposed to work around it? I can't always start recording a beat early because often there is something else there that will get overwritten?

Comment: This deserves an answer, but as a workaround, I suppose you could actually start recording a full bar early and then manually trim that bar off.

Comment: Try recording GarageBand's own output to see if there's a latency compensation problem. Disable monitoring to avoid feedback, connect the Presonus's output to its input with a cable, set GarageBand to play a metronome click, and record that on an audio track. Is the recorded click on time or off the grid?

Comment: Practical solutions, whether the latency is badly compensated or not… 1. Use another track. 2. Start recording earlier & trim afterwards; the head of the note is more important in an edit than the tail of the previous. Crossfade if you need to.

Comment: @Tetsujin one thing I only realised later is that when over-recording, the previous region is _still there_ hidden/overlapped not truncated so you can slide the join between regions. This helps a lot to just start re-recording a bar earlier and sort it out later

Comment: @Mr.Boy As far as I know, most DAWs automatically handle latency and buffering when recording, so that _everything_ is recorded, but depending on your workflow, you might only see a part in a particular clip/region/sequence.